# How to display user's avatar in website using Discord Oauth2

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I want to display a user's avatar after he authorizes. I have written a code that displays its Username.
But I am not able to display its avatar can somebody please help me. Thanks

Also can somebody please tell me how you can connect two HTML files as I have two HTML files so how do I do it here:

```
else res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
```

This is the code in my HTML:

```
<script>
         function generateRandomString() {
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            let randStr = '';
 
            for (let i = 0; i < 20 + rand; i++) {
                randStr += String.fromCharCode(33 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 94));
            }
 
            return randStr;
        }
 
        window.onload = function () {
            const fragment = parseQuery(window.location.href);
            if (fragment.access_token) {
                const urlState = fragment.state;
                const stateParameter = localStorage.getItem('stateParameter');
                if (stateParameter !== atob(decodeURIComponent(urlState))) {
                    return console.log('You may have been clickjacked!');
                }
 
                const accessToken = fragment.access_token;
                const tokenType = fragment.token_type;
 
                fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
                    headers: {
                        authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`
                    }
                })
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        const { username, discriminator } = response;
                         
                        console.log(username, discriminator);
                        document.getElementById('info').textContent = ` ${username}#${discriminator}`;
                    })
                    .catch(console.error);
            } else {
                const randStr = generateRandomString();
                localStorage.setItem('stateParameter', randStr);
 
                document.getElementById('login').href += `&state=${encodeURIComponent(btoa(randStr))}`;
                document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        function parseQuery(queryString) {
            var query = {};
            var pairs = (queryString[0] === '?' ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
                query[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
            }
            return query;
        }
    </script>
```

And this is the HTML that displays users username:

```
<h5 id="info">hi</h5>
```

And this is my javascript file code:

```
const app = require('express')();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let access_token;
    let token_type;
    if (req.query.code) {
        const accessCode = req.query.code;
        const data = {
            client_id     : 'My client id',
            client_secret : 'My client secret',
            grant_type    : 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri  : 'http://localhost:3000',
            code          : accessCode,
            scope         : 'identify'
        };

        const res = await fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token', {
            method  : 'POST',
            body    : new URLSearchParams(data),
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
        const info = await res.json();
        token_type = info.token_type;
        access_token = info.access_token;
        const post = await fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
            headers : {
                authorization : `${token_type} ${access_token}`
            }
        });
        const user = await post.json();
    }

    if (token_type && access_token && req.query.state) {
        res
            .status(200)
            .redirect(
                `http://localhost:3000/?code=${req.query.code}&state=${req.query
                    .state}&access_token=${access_token}&token_type=${token_type}`
            );
    } else res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: `const { username, discriminator } = response;` should probably also contain the avatar URL, then set is as `src` for an `<img>`? Also, you server-side code seems to be overwriting express' `res` object, so I don't see that working at all?

Comment: Yes, how can I fix that?